Python: How to type a Union of TypeVarTuple
I have a function that receives 3 parameters: a: dict[str, str], b:dict[str, str], and c: dict[str, str].
The values/keys of these parameters are "linked". They are based on a existing protocol and some combinations are not possible.
The keys in b and c will differ depending on a certain key in a.
I have all the possible states and their combinations typed out.
type combination1 = tuple[SomeTypeA, SomeTypeB, SomeTypeC]
type combination2 = tuple[SomeTypeA2, SomeTypeB2, SomeTypeC3]
...

def function(state: combination1 | combination2):
    a, b, c = state
   
    if a["type"] == "1":
        _ = b["some_key"] # this works
        _ = b["some_other_key"] # typehints say that this key doesn't exist

    if a["type"] == "2":
        _ = b["some_key"] # typehints say that this key doesn't exist
        _ = b["some_other_key"] # this works

The above works without a problem but my function should have a signature of function(a, b, c) -> None with 3 parameters instead of function(state) -> None. The function is used as a callback by another package and expects this signature.
Using *args the function would run but type hinting works for only one combination:
def function(*args: *combination1):
    a, b, c = args
   
    if a["type"] == "1":
        _ = b["some_key"] # this works
        _ = b["some_other_key"] # typehints say that this key doesn't exist

If the following was allowed then my issue would be fixed, but it isn't.
def function(*args: *combination1 | *combination2):
    a, b, c = args
   
    if a["type"] == "1":
        _ = b["some_key"] # this works
        _ = b["some_other_key"] # typehints say that this key doesn't exist

This last piece of code returns an invalid syntax error: "Unpack operator not allowed in type annotation"
Any ideas on how to solve this, preferably only with typehints without typing.TypeGuard using custom logic?

You cannot. It will run if you use *args: *comb1 | comb2 (only one unpacking, it applies to whole expression), but mypy says that ... cannot be unpacked (must be tuple or TypeVarTuple). Additionally, your approach won't work even without *args: as soon as you do a, b, c = args, all of a, b, c become expanded to unions of corresponding members and are no longer dependent. You'd want if args[0]['type'] == 1: a, b, c = args, ... - then b and c will be inferred to one type correctly.

@STerliakov not using the unpacking operator state: comb1 | comb2 and then a, b, c = state does seem to work using Pyright, but maybe other type checking libraries behave differently.

Since the types of b and c appear to depend on the type of a, I think you need to use typing.overload.
from typing import overload


@overload
def function(a: SomeTypeA, b: SomeTypeB, c: SomeTypeC):
    ...


@overload
def function(a: SomeTypeA2, b: SomeTypeB2, c: SomeTypeC3):
    ...


def function(a, b, c):   
    if a["type"] == "1":
        _ = b["some_key"] # this works
        _ = b["some_other_key"] # typehints say that this key doesn't exist

    if a["type"] == "2":
        _ = b["some_key"] # typehints say that this key doesn't exist
        _ = b["some_other_key"] # this works


This only works for type hinting the function itself, not it's body. When calling the function the type checker will check against all the overloads if the given parameters are valid but the types within the function are now Unknown so no type checking will happen there.

For the body, you'd want to annotate the args with union types, and then narrow them with isinstance checks as needed.
